# Installing Bookworm on Ubuntu 20.04 Failed due to Unresolvable Dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Using the synaptic package manager, I got this message: The following packages have unresolvable dependencies:

com.github.babluboy.bookworm: Depends: ninja  but it is not installable

Installing the ninja-build package did not help.

Entering sudo apt-get install bookworm in a terminal window didn't help. I got the error message "Unable to locate package bookworm".

Suggestions?

Comment: It turns out that others have already opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm/issues/325). The workaround using Flatpak worked for me.

Comment: `sudo apt install com.github.babluboy.bookworm`, but it gives the same error

Answer (score 3):

You can get binary [deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ninja) from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS directly by

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ninja/ninja_0.1.3-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./ninja_0.1.3-2_amd64.deb
```

and install Bookworm from [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebablu-boy/+archive/ubuntu/bookworm-daily?field.series_filter=focal).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Please consider adding it to the issue page on [GitHub](https://github.com/babluboy/bookworm/issues/325) mentioned in my reply to the comment from @user535733.

Comment: Done, so you can accept my answer here :)

Comment: I didn't use your answer so I don't feel that I can accept it. I used the Flatpak workaround found on the GitHub issue page. Thanks for adding your suggestion to the issue page for those who don't want to try Flatpak.